# How to optimize DynamoDb's Indexes

Tags: java, indexing, amazon-dynamodb

We are in the process of evaluating DynamoDb, and whether or not it makes sense for us to use it.

Currently, we have a relational db with roughly 70K rows.  For the sake of simplicity, let say the schema has 4 fields, with two indexes (vendor_name, contract_number).

```
vendor_name|contract_number|vendor_code|address
-------------------------------------------------
ABC Corp   |123            |abc        |1 Main St.
123 Corp   |456            |ott        |1 Off Main St.
```

Is it possible, with Dynamo, to allow for searching on either `vendor_name` or `contract_number` and have the query use the index to retrieve the results?  From what I'm reading online, it seems as though this might not be an option.

Thank you.

Comment: Possibly [Global Secondary Indexes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html)?

Comment: In my prototype, I did that and it's taking over 2 days to create the index for 75K records

Comment: You didn't mention that.  I believe indexes can only be created as fast as their subscribed write throughput will allow. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.OnlineOps.html#GSI.OnlineOps.Creating

Comment: Sorry, wasnt sure how relevant it would be.  Also, within my prototype, I created the primary key as the `contract_number` and my secondary key (ALL values) as `vendor_name`

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB would be able to handle a query workload that included lookups on `contract_number` and `vendor_name`. If you use `contract_number` as the partition key and `vendor_name` as the sort key of your base table, your base table will be able to handle both Query lookups of all vendors on a particular contract, and GetItem lookups for a particular vendor on a contract. Also, you can add a Global Secondary Index (GSI) to enable lookup of all contracts by vendor name. The schema of this GSI would have a partition key of `vendor_name` and a sort key of `contract number`.

Comment: It's possible to use one or the other, correct?  Meaning I know I can search using both, but if I wanted to search on just `vendor_name` or `contract_number`, my current setup would allow for it.